# Create new column in Python and use value from previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im totally beginner in Python but I need to use the value from previous row. I read a lot of articles but I didn't catch the point :(

I have an Excel file with data, I sorted the data by 'D_i' column and here I found a problem. I need to add new column 'C_i' which contains in 1st row value from column 'Time', but in 2nd row and other ones I need to add the value from 2nd row from 'Time' column and value from 1st row in 'C_i' column.

Final layout should looks like this:

[image]

below is the 'code' (I got stuck at the beginning...)

```
import pandas as pd
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

dane = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/artur/Desktop/Studia/V semestr/IO/Sprawozdanie1_dane.xlsx')
daneSortowane = dane.sort_values('Termin (D_i)')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) check uggly way as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I think what you're after is `pd.cumsum()`, so I think `dansSortowane['C_i'] = daneSortowane['Time'].cumsum()` is what you're after?

Comment: omg, thanks EMI OB ! It was so simple but I tried to create a loops, doing strange things, but it's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @focus87krk I've written a proper answer, if it helped it would be great if you  could upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is known as a cumulative sum. There is a built in function for this in pandas already, [pd.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

From what I can gather from your question, adding the line:

```
daneSortowane['C_i'] = daneSortowane['Time'].cumsum()
```

Will add your C_i column as required.